# Javascript This Change Value

Tags: javascript

How could I correct this behavior so `this` inside `is.green` refers to the `new book()`.  Because I'm convinced there isn't a way.

```
function book(){}
book.prototype.is = function(){};

book.prototype.is.green = function(){
  alert(this);
  // this should refer to 'new book' not  `is` function
  return this;
};

var Book = new book();

Book.is.green();
```

## TLDR

**Is there a way to construct an new prototype object for each `new book` that could hold the correct reference?  Are there any other potential techniques?**

## No wrapper functions/altering the book function

Comment: As is, without changes to your code structure, you're right, there is no way to do it. Binding won't work because the function is shared in the prototype, and by default the runtime will assign `this` to be the instance's `is` property, which isn't the instance itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
book.prototype.is = function(){ return this; }
Book.is().green();
```

or (I know you said you didn't want to alter the constructor, but):

```
function book(){ this.is = this; }
Book.is.green();
```

or (non-cross-browser):

```
book.prototype = {
    get is(){ return this; }
};
Book.is.green();
```

What's the point of this?  Just to have the word "is" needlessly placed somewhere?  What's wrong with `Book.isGreen()`?

Comment: Thanks for the futuristic solution, I was just attempting to avoid polluting the objs properties, so I could easily cycle through it using a `for(var i in obj)` loop. :D  You know just having some fun...

Comment: FYI, also non-cross browser (but more compatible than the last example) is `Object.defineProperty('propName', function(){ ... })` which will, by default, make the property non-enumerable so it won't show up in your for-in loop

Comment: Yeah I was aware of that property, but obviously being non cross browser it provides no real world functionality. %) IE..shrug  I actually have different intentions for my question above, that could solve this whole sub classing issue.

Comment: It provides real-world functionality, just not if you need to support IE8.  I use it in node.js all the time.

Comment: Yeah node.js is pretty slick, and provides your own separate `Array`,`String`...(So you can add your own custom prototypes) for each module, and its api is pretty slick to.  I have enjoyed using it.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you have each method on your object return the base object then `this` will be what you want.

A bit like how jQuery methods always return a reference to the jQuery object.